# Predicate CONTAINS doesn't return records with NOLOCK

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, contains, nolock, read-uncommitted

I am writing integration tests and I use TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled) for this purpose.
I add some data to DB (MS SQL Server) and then check the result, compare it etc.
When the test is passed, new data will not be saved in DB.
So this approach worked always fine. When I debug test I can check new records in DB, e. g.

```
  SELECT * FROM Users
  WITH(NOLOCK)
  Where UserId = 2
```

But now I need to check the CONTAINS predicate when I debug my test, e. g.

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE CONTAINS(Surname, 'White')
```

And this query returns only present records in my DB, but it doesn't return the uncommitted record, which I add in my test.
The field "Surname" of course accepts full-text search.
I have read information about predicate CONTAINS, but I didn't find the answer.
Can predicate Contains work with uncommitted records ? If yes, how can it be done ?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you instead change the isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`?

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the full-text catalog being maintained by a separate process, not by the database engine. Your uncommitted data probably isn't being handed off to the indexing process. Suggested reading: [Hands on Full-Text Search in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/hands-full-text-search-sql-server/).

Comment: @Larnu yes, the same behaviour. LIKE predicate works with uncommitted records without any problem. CONTAINS predicate doesn't work. I don't know now if it is possible that CONTAINS will work with uncommitted records.